# Creating the sum of two matrix rows of unequally dimensioned matrices

Tags: r, matrix, addition, dimensions

I have a matrix with n rows and another matrix with just 1 row. The number of columns is the same in both. I would like to add the one row of the latter matrix to each of the former matrix. Is there an easy way to do this? I can't seem to figure it out.

Example:

What I have:

```
a <- matrix(c(1, 1, 1, 1), nrow = 2)
b <- matrix(c(1, 1), nrow = 1)

a
    [,1] [,2]
[1,]   1    1
[2,]   1    1

b
    [,1] [,2]
[1,]   1    1
```

The result I want:

```
       [,1] [,2]
[1,]   2    2
[2,]   2    2
```

Is there a quick and easy way to achieve this? The best I could do so far was to basically repeat the second matrix (b) to match the number of rows of the first matrix (a) and then doing a regular addition (+), but this is quite a lot of effort for something pretty simple. Thanks!

Comment: You can use `sweep` - `sweep(a, 2, b, \`+\`)`

Comment: Also `apply(a, 1, function(x) x + b)`